# asterisk Unable to connect SIP socket to ip:port Connection timed out

Tags: tcp, sip, asterisk

I am working on a sip client - asterisk server. I am using tcp connections.

The client side is Zoiper as for a first test.
Registration and outbound calls do work as expected, but after 3-4 minutes from registration process or an outgoing call, when testing incoming calls I do get this message on the server:

tcptls.c:446 ast_tcptls_client_start: Unable to connect SIP socket to ip:port: Connection timed out

The invite message (incoming call) never gets on the client (Zoiper softphone).

Why is this error showing up?
The reason why this appears from my assumption is because of the fact that neither the client or the server are sending keep alive messages, so after a tcp socket timeout the client which is behind a nat will not be reachable from the server side anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error come because your NAT (or 3g if you use 3g) drop connection. As result there are no way use same connection anymore.

Correct behavour of you app - send SIP OPTIONS message, if timeout - do registration again.

And yes, you need send keepalives(recomended  method - OPTIONS message) or setup keepalive on asterisk side and setup in your side correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I am re-registering the client every 10 minutes. But between these 10 minutes there is no keep alive mechanism neither on the client neither on the server. Is it possible for the server to open a new socket to the client that s behind a nat? Is there any way? I don t want to keep tcp sockets open on the server if they are not used. Could you give me some suggestions in this case?

Comment: P.S I want to timeout the connection before the new reregistration because, as I mentioned, I don t want to mainain open connection on the server. it s not efficient for a huge number oof sip clients, is it?

Comment: no, there are no any way for SERVER!!!! open socket on CLIENT!!!. If you  not want keepalives, use tunnel, or use udp or program your own-special-nat-server.

Comment: what about stun? Is it possible to configure a stun sending keep alive messages to the client in order to mantain the socket open and when having incoming messages the server will be able to send the packet to the client, case the router has the mapping table?

Comment: do you think this is a sollution? Thank you for your time:)

Comment: stun is not designed to send anything except info about ip. you can configure asterisk to send keepalive(quality=1000) or you can do that on your client.

Comment: from my client I am sending keep alive messages but still after 2 minutes i can t make any call or receive any call. Is there a timeout on tcp sockets?

Comment: Sure all sockets have timeout. Usualy near 10-15 minutes but also can be 20 sec on some overloaded NAT gates.

Comment: from my client I am sending keep alive messages but still after 2 minutes i can t make any call or receive any call. Is there a timeout on tcp sockets? Is is possible somehow for the server to update socket without announcing the client? Could this be a reason why calls do not work?

Comment: I am sorry,it is your work. I am not gooing do your work for you.